# Is it possible to install XAMPP with a UI wizard in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: software-installation, xampp

I am very new to Ubuntu. I've downloaded XAMPP as a tar, extracted it, but didn't know what to do with the extracted material. There is no `.exe` link such as in Windows. I was seeing some Youtube videos and all I found was showing installation via the terminal. I have also  searched in Google for **XAMPP Ubuntu install** and **AskUbuntu XAMPP UI** but I only found articles that didn't deal with a UI install solely.

Is there way to install XAMPP via the UI/GUI ?

Comment: As far as I know, its a straight forward procedure using the terminal and then you can apply a GUI to control the services. I do not know of any GUI method for this. However, why don't you try the **LAMP** instead which can be done just with a single command.

Comment: I've installed LAMP manually via several commands... At least the next time I will do so again and only after that will I allow myself to install it with the single command :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and use the below command to unpack the downloaded XAMPP file.

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-0.0.0.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Once extraction is complete start the service.

Or

You can try GUI control using below commands:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't there UI-only way of installing it from the tar?

Comment: You can try installing it through the Ubuntu Software Center which is the Orange icon with an A on it in your toolbar... you can search for the program there, however not all programs are there, so check and see!

Comment: Seems they have yet to add it to there :)